# How to map String variable to name of an integer?

Tags: java, string, integer, mapping

Suppose I have a String Variable like this in Java:

String cat = "felix";

int felix = 6;

Is there some way in Java that I could compare the contents of cat - "felix" to the name of the int variable felix?

Comment: No, there is not. At least not with variable names. We can, however, use a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with the method you are doing, but you can use hashmap:

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("felix", 6);
myMap.put("another key", -4);
int value = myMap.get("felix");
System.out.println(value);//prints 6
value = myMap.get("abc");//throws null pointer exception
```

Comment: This approach is not `null`-safe. If no mapping for a given `String` exists, it will throw a `NullPointerException` ([Ideone demo](https://ideone.com/qfIHG0)). It is also not what OP asked for. We should rather ask for clarification in the comments instead of posting speculative answers.